# Resultant LinQ Query to a new DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

Refer to earlier post/Question: 
**[LINQ to Swap few Columns to Rows of a DataTable using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915558/linq-to-swap-few-columns-to-rows-of-a-datatable-using-c-sharp)**

I want the resultant of the query interms of a new dataTable directly instead of defining columns in the new datatable.

**Refer to the above post question the LINQ Query `newset` is**:

```
var newSet = dt.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Location"))
           .Select(g => new
           {
                Location = g.Key,
                ppl_required_Q1 = g.Where(p => p.Field<string>("Quarter") == "Q1").Sum(p => p.Field<int>("ppl_required")),
                ppl_required_Q2 = g.Where(p => p.Field<string>("Quarter") == "Q2").Sum(p => p.Field<int>("ppl_required")),
                ppl_required_Q3 = g.Where(p => p.Field<string>("Quarter") == "Q3").Sum(p => p.Field<int>("ppl_required")),
                ppl_required_Q4 = g.Where(p => p.Field<string>("Quarter") == "Q4").Sum(p => p.Field<int>("ppl_required")),
                ppl_available_Q1 = g.Where(p => p.Field<string>("Quarter") == "Q1").Sum(p => p.Field<int>("ppl_available")),
                ppl_available_Q2 = g.Where(p => p.Field<string>("Quarter") == "Q2").Sum(p => p.Field<int>("ppl_available")),
                ppl_available_Q3 = g.Where(p => p.Field<string>("Quarter") == "Q3").Sum(p => p.Field<int>("ppl_available")),
                ppl_available_Q4 = g.Where(p => p.Field<string>("Quarter") == "Q4").Sum(p => p.Field<int>("ppl_available")),
            });
```

How to get the `newset` resultant collection in a new datatable directly without any loop through? Is it possible in LINQ??

Comment: The `newset` object relates to which **type** of collection? Mean to which type it is??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newset.CopyToDataTable();
```

[Check this Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx)

Comment: I didn't find `CopyToDataTable()` in the intellisense window after typing `.`

Comment: Hi Sukumar Check the link below it may help you

Comment: The `newset` object relates to which **type** of collection? Mean to which type it is??